# LPT circuit switching

Tags: control-circuit

Is there a short tutorial describing simple, low voltage circuit switching using the LPT port?

I know it could be done using USB or RS 232 relays, but I would like to assemble it with (buying) minimum or none electronic components, except things I have: an LPT cable, a LED diode or a fan, and a 12 V adapter.

Comment: "a LED diode or a fan"  How can you have one or the other?  Is this a student project, perchance?

Comment: Yes it is, although I'm not a student, or is this homework or test.

Comment: Where do you even find a computer with a parallel port these days?

Comment: Now that's a constructive comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

[Parallel Port Controlled LEDs](http://www.cleghornelectronicskits.com/parallel-port-controlled-leds/)

Comment: by copying inpout32.dll you'll opening your door to many bad things.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: Source code for that DLL is freely available. You can check it and compile yourself, if you are concerned with safety.